# How do I get the missing dates from a range

Tags: c#, date

I'm doing this test-app and what it has to do is go through a long list of dates from a text file and get the missing ones (excluding weekend days) and write the results to an output file. If the missing date is a single day the output should be ccyy/mm/dd , if it's more than one day it should be ccyy/mm/dd - ccyy/mm/dd , so this is what I've come up with and it doesn't seem to work as it should, I think I'm not doing the test right.

```
List<string> missigDateStrings = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < dateList.Count; i++ )
{
    DateTime firstDate = dateList[i];
    DateTime secondDate = dateList[i + 1];

    if (firstDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && 
        firstDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        if (secondDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && 
            secondDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            if (firstDate.AddDays(1) != secondDate)
            {
                string sFirstMissingDate = firstDate.ToShortDateString();
                DateTime testDate = firstDate;
                while (testDate != secondDate)
                        {
                            testDate.AddDays(1);
                            if (testDate == secondDate)
                            {
                                string sLastMissingDate = firstDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();
                                string range = String.Format("{0}-{1}", sFirstMissingDate, sLastMissingDate);
                                missigDateStrings.Add(range);
                            }

                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. all the dates have been converted to DateTime

EXCELLENT ! THANKS ALL

Comment: What means "it doesn't seem to work as it should"?

Comment: it's not giving me any output at all, the missingDateStrings list stays empty

Comment: debug and check where the things going wrong.

Comment: I've just checked, the AddDays() method is not changing the date at all , it stays the same , any clues ?

Comment: Just saw the when testdate == secondDate that the While breaks so it can't add to missingDateStrings so that code will never be called

Comment: Is there way to preemptively add the string to the list on the day before a true test?

Comment: This is the kind of simple, descreet task where TDD really shines.

Comment: `DateTime` is immutable. So simply calling `AddDays()` will not change the actual value of your variable. You need to assign it to the same variable. Like: `testDate = testDate.AddDays(1)`

Comment: Your `while` loop is not doing anything useful anyway... It's only incrementing date. You can skip this and just write string with difference between `firstDate` and `secondDate` and results will be the same. What you really should do is check in that loop for weekend days. Otherwise this loop is not needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the gap is longer than 7 days you get weekend days also. I assume that is your problem. So you should add another check for Sat/Sun in

```
while (testDate != secondDate)
```

and break the loop on Friday, skip weekend and start loop on Monday again.

EDIT:

Below is always false in your case probably. That's why you don't get any output.

```
if (firstDate == secondDate)
```

Comment: so how should I be doing the test?

Comment: testDate = testDate.AddDays(1);

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 testDate.AddDays(1);
```

to

```
 testDate = testDate.AddDays(1);
```

DateTime is an immutable value-type, `AddDays()` returns a *new* instance but does not (cannot) change the original value.

And just for fun, to answer the title-question,

```
var missing = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
          .Select(i => baseDate.AddDays(i))
          .Except(datesFromFile);
```